# Why is the "Last version before deletion" much shorter than the message I see in the "Message history" right before the deletion?

Tags: support, chat

I see on https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/64322151/history ([mirror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEyyD.jpg), [mirror with the entire history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbHek.jpg)) that the "Last version before deletion" is much shorter than the message I see in the Message history right before the deletion. Why?

---

In the screenshot below, I pointed to the "Last version before deletion" (timestamp: 7:01pm), as well as to the message I see in the Message history right before the deletion (timestamp: 7:03pm).

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with deletion. It's just how chat normally handles very long multi-line messages. The only difference caused by the deletion is that instead of "Current version" that section of the history page is titled "Last version before deletion".

The "Last version before deletion" section is what would have been displayed when the chat message was first loaded in a page. That chat message is a multi-line chat message which exceeds the length which is displayed by default in chat pages. What's shown in the "Last version before deletion" section would have been displayed with a button underneath it that said "(see full text)". When that button was clicked, then the entire chat message would have been loaded and displayed in a scrollable area, allowing the reader to see then entire text without too much of the page being taken up by the single message.

As an example of a multi-line message which isn't deleted, you can see [this message of mine](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=59028653#59028653) and [that message's history page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/59028653/history).